# Typescript type/interface for strings of a given length

Tags: typescript

Say my function f takes an argument, x, of type string. But not any string, only strings of length n.

Is it possible to enforce this using the type system?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to do this in Typescript as types.

Comment: There is an open proposal for [regex-validated types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) though, but nothing you can do currently.